# Solve the equation: $x^4+8x-7=0$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

> Solve the following equation: $$x^4+8x-7=0$$

I tried the form $x(x+2)(x^2-2x+4)-7=0$, but I can't see the solution. It looks easy but I'm having a hard time with this problem.

Comment: You can try Rational root theorem. That form is useless unless you are trying to find integer root. If you want to find a useful form then it should have the form $A\times B\times C\times ... = 0$.

Comment: I think I tried that, for example, tried to prove that f(7), f(-7), f(1), f(-1) = 0 but I cant find any solution.

Comment: ok, thanks ,I will try that!

Comment: Hint: $x^4 + 8x - 7 = (x^2+\sqrt{2} x-2 \sqrt{2}+1)(x^2-\sqrt{2} x+2 \sqrt{2}+1)$.

Comment: @Santiago how did you find that decomposition?

Answer (score 1):

Following Santiago's suggestion in the comments, your question is equivalent to finding the zeros of

$$f(x)= (x^2 + x\sqrt{2} - (2\sqrt{2}-1))(x^2 - x\sqrt{2} + (2\sqrt{2}+1))$$

$f(x)=0$ when either one or both of the factors equal zero. So you need to find $x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4$ such that

$$x_{1,2} = \frac{-b_1\pm\sqrt{b_1^2-4a_1c_1}}{2a_1}$$

$$x_{3,4} = \frac{-b_2\pm\sqrt{b_2^2-4a_2c_2}}{2a_2}$$

where $a_1 = a_2 = 1$, $b_1 = \sqrt{2}$, $b_2 = -\sqrt{2}$, $c_1 = -2\sqrt{2}+1$, and $c_2 =2\sqrt{2}+1$.

You should be able to go on from here.